# Given $\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x^2}dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$, evaluate $\int_0^{\infty}e^{-a^2x^2-\frac{b^2}{x^2}}dx $

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

> Given $$\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x^2}dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$$ evaluate:
>   $$\int_0^{\infty}e^{-a^2x^2-\frac{b^2}{x^2}}dx. $$

I can find that 
$$\left(ax+\frac{b}{x}\right)^2 = a^2x^2+2ab+\frac{b^2}{x^2}$$

therefore:
$$\int_0^{\infty}e^{-a^2x^2-\frac{b^2}{x^2}}dx = e^{2ab}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-\left(ax+\frac{b}{x}\right)^2}dx$$

but I can't find any clue then.

Comment: I think that setting $t = ax + b/x $ and using integration by parts two times should work. Note also that the minus should be outside the square in the exponent

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming $a,b>0$, you have:
$$ I= e^{-2ab}\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-(ax-b/x)^2}\,dx = e^{-2ab}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1+\color{blue}{\frac{z}{\sqrt{4ab+z^2}}}}{2a}\,e^{-z^2}\,dz $$
through the substitution $ax-\frac{b}{x}=z$, but the contribute given by the blue term vanishes by symmetry, hence:

> $$ I = \color{red}{\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2a\, e^{2ab}}}.$$

Comment: Neat trick!  It does implicitly assume $a> 0$ and $b > 0$ for the limits of integration to work, though.  I think the general result for general $a$ and $b$ can be obtained by taking $a \to |a|$ and $b \to |b|$.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert: absolutely right.